# register_shutdown_function converting references to values?

Tags: php, reference

I'm trying to use a shutdown function that uses a value changed dynamically after registration. My understanding was that passing the variable by reference would allow changes in later portions of the code to affect the shutdown call. The code below demonstrates that this is not the case:

```
<?php
    $x = 0;
    function shutdown(&$x) {echo $x;}
    register_shutdown_function('shutdown',$x);
    $x = 1;
    exit();
?>
```

Am I misunderstanding how this should be done? Is it expected behavior for the register function to convert the reference pass to a value pass?

PHP version 5.5.9

Comment: Yes. I thought that my understanding was correct. david dot schueler at tel-billig dot de on that page references something similar.

Comment: Why do you need that at first place?

Comment: I'm registering a shutdown function at the beginning of a file, and I shouldn't have to re-register each time there's a change to one of the parameters that I'd like to have accessible in it.

Comment: that's right, but what is the original task you're solving with this code? The whole idea with passing references to a shutdown function just doesn't look right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to use anonymous functions (it's a closure in this case with `$x` captured as a reference):

```
$x = 0;

$shutdown = function() use(&$x) { echo $x; };

register_shutdown_function($shutdown);
$x = 1;

exit();
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/L2cYJp

**UPD**: Explanation why your solution doesn't work:

If you have a look on `register_shutdown_function` signature:

```
void register_shutdown_function ( callable $callback [, mixed $parameter [, mixed $... ]] )
```

you will see that parameters are passed by values. That's it - the value of `$x` in `register_shutdown_function('shutdown',$x);` line is passed by value and equals to the value it was on the moment of call.

If doesn't matter if you defined your function that accepts a reference since it's too late to accept a reference because you have already lost reference (indirectly, by using a function that does not take it into account).

Comment: Thank you! This will definitely serve my needs, although I'm still confused about the behavior of register_shutdown_function itself.

Comment: @TheToolBox: I'll add an explanation for `register_shutdown_function` then. UPD: Done.

Comment: Quite helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Something I ran into: I converted a named function to an anonymous closure so I could use this, but you need to remember to have the semicolon after the function assignment (after the ending brace, as shown in the code in this answer). Don't know why it took me awhile to find this, but hopefully it helps someone else.

Comment: @JoshH yep, you need that because an anonymous function is a part of an expression. And a function declaration is a statement.